# Copying a string to a pointer doesn't seem to work

Tags: c, string, pointers, copy

I have this structure of `Node`

```
typedef struct Node{
  unsigned int length;
  char *string;
} Node;
```

And this operation which accepts a pointer to a `Node` and tries to attach the provided string:

```
int setString(Node *node, char *string){

  char *newString;
  if(!isString(node) || !string) return 0;

  newString = (char *) malloc(strlen(string)+1);
  if(!newString) return 0;

  /*THIS PART FAILS*/
  strncpy(newString,string,sizeof(newString));

  node->string = newString;
  node->length = strlen(newString);

  /*Which can be seen here*/
  printf("Original String: %s\n",string);
  printf("Copied String: %s\n",node->string);

  return 1;
}
```

At the indicated part, I can see that the original string doesn't seem be copied over to `node->string`. It copies over the first two characters, and then what follows is either garbage or just blank.

I checked this post and I am following the third case, which seems to work for the OP. Maybe I overlooked something, but just can't figure out where

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
strncpy(newString,string,sizeof(newString));
```

In this context `sizeof` doesn't do what you want. Pass the size you allocated or **don't use `strncpy`**.  If you follow your own logic, you already trust `string` **since you took its `strlen`** when you called `malloc`.

So you can safely use `strcpy` instead.

---

If you're willing to go a little non-portable, you could get away with:

```
newString = strdup(string);
```

Comment: In addition, which research did you do before asking this question? There's a [c-faq.com frequently asked question](http://c-faq.com/malloc/sizeof.html) that answers this! If you have to ask this question to us, then I'd suggest that your method of learning isn't working too well for you.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue pardon my C, there's this gap between JS and C that I'm trying to cross, especially memory allocation. Thanks for that reference :)

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Fortunately, a monkey can learn Javascript by mashing it's face on the keyboard. It's unwise to learn C this way, because that which appears to work initially may be plagued with unportable and *undefined behavior*. I suggest reading a book.

Answer (score 1):

Your sizeof() call is causing your problem:

```
sizeof(newString);
```

newString is a pointer to a character is declared here:

```
char *newString;
```

And character pointers use (normally) 2,4 or 8 bytes (depending on the machines architecture).
So it's clear, that you are only copy the first 2/4/8 bytes. Use `strlen(string) + 1` for the number of characters to copy.

Or you can just use `strcpy()`. This will take care of the terminating null byte. Since you are calling `malloc()` correctly with `strlen` there is no chance to cause a overflow with `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the `sizeof()` in order to determine the string length.

You have to use the `strlen(string)` function instead.

Also you need to set `\0` after copied symbols to terminate the string.

Comment: Yeh... And strncpy will terminate the fixed width field as a string if it can, and in this case it can.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try directly this:

```
strncpy(node->string,string,strlen(newString));
```

Changing the length function to **strlen**.

(i tried to make the changes in code to bold)

Comment: This will not work either. `newString` is declared as a **pointer** to a charater. `sizeof()` will return size of that pointer.

Comment: i agree, how about changing the length function also.

Comment: @flyingOwl I would be most upset if the sizeof *operator* were to *return*.